# New pandas dataframe column with totals from a different dataframe by conditions (similar to Excel's SUMIFS)

Tags: python, pandas

I have two tables: one ('sales') with sales data (types of goods, dates of sale, and quantity) and another ('ref') with types of goods and a reference date.

I want to add a column to the second table that would show the total quantity of the corresponding item sold within seven days (give or take) from the reference date.

Here's the sample data:

```
sales = pd.DataFrame({'Fruit': {0: 'apples',  1: 'oranges',  2: 'pears',  3: 'apples',  4: 'apples',  5: 'bananas',  6: 'oranges', 7: 'pears',  8: 'pears',  9: 'oranges',  10: 'bananas',  11: 'apples',  12: 'pears',  13: 'pears', 14: 'apples',  15: 'pears',  16: 'oranges',  17: 'oranges',  18: 'pears'},
                      'Date': {0: '2023-07-07',  1: '2023-02-05',  2: '2023-08-16',  3: '2023-07-26',  4: '2023-07-14', 5: '2024-02-01',  6: '2023-09-19',  7: '2023-04-08',  8: '2023-06-08',  9: '2023-05-15', 10: '2023-10-20',  11: '2023-07-25',  12: '2023-07-31',  13: '2023-10-08',  14: '2023-06-28', 15: '2023-08-15',  16: '2023-05-14',  17: '2023-07-28',  18: '2023-07-29'},
                      'Quantity': {0: 18,  1: 10,  2: 10,  3: 20,  4: 16,  5: 14,  6: 18,  7: 18,  8: 14,  9: 19,  10: 16, 11: 16,  12: 17,  13: 10,  14: 16,  15: 15,  16: 18,  17: 20,  18: 19}})
sales['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(sales['Date'])

ref = pd.DataFrame({'Fruit': {0: 'apples', 1: 'bananas',  2: 'oranges',  3: 'apples',  4: 'pears', 5: 'oranges',  6: 'bananas',  7: 'oranges',  8: 'oranges'}, 
                    'Date': {0: '2023-07-25',  1: '2023-12-27',  2: '2023-07-13',  3: '2023-06-27',  4: '2023-07-08',  5: '2023-09-17', 6: '2023-10-25',  7: '2023-10-05',  8: '2023-04-14'}})
ref['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(ref['Date'])
```

For example, the first row of ref should show 36 (20 apples from 2023-07-36 and 16 apples from 2023-07-25).

If I were using Excel, I'd use this formula: =SUMIFS(sales.Quantity, sales.Fruit, ref.Fruit, sales.Date, ">="&ref.Date-7, sales.Date, "<="&ref.Date+7).

In Python, I can get the results I needed on a single-item basis, like this:

```
sales[(sales['Fruit']=='apples')&
      (sales['Date']>=pd.to_datetime('2023-07-25')-pd.to_timedelta(7, unit='d'))&
      (sales['Date']<=pd.to_datetime('2023-07-25')+pd.to_timedelta(7, unit='d'))]['Quantity'].sum()
```

and using iloc:

```
sales[(sales['Fruit']==ref.iloc[0,0])&
      (sales['Date']>=ref.iloc[0,1]-pd.to_timedelta(7, unit='d'))&
      (sales['Date']<=ref.iloc[0,1]+pd.to_timedelta(7, unit='d'))]['Quantity'].sum()
```

but when I try to add a new column to ref with this calculation, I get 'ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects'.

```
ref['Total'] = sales[(sales['Fruit']==ref.iloc[ref.index,0])&
      (sales['Date']>=ref.iloc[ref.index,1]-pd.to_timedelta(7, unit='d'))&
      (sales['Date']<=ref.iloc[ref.index,1]+pd.to_timedelta(7, unit='d'))]['Quantity'].sum()
```

I'm guessing I'm wrong to use ref.index in place of the 0 in iloc to get the number I need - what should I use instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`conditional_join`](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.conditional_join.conditional_join) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/):

```
ref['start'] = ref['Date'] - pd.to_timedelta(7, unit='d')
ref['end'] = ref['Date'] + pd.to_timedelta(7, unit='d')

out = (sales
      .conditional_join(
           ref,
           ('Date', 'end', '<='),
           ('Date', 'start', '>='),
           ('Fruit', 'Fruit', '=='),
           how='right',
          df_columns='Quantity')
     .groupby(['Fruit', 'Date'], as_index=False)['Quantity']
     .sum())
print (out)
     Fruit       Date  Quantity
0   apples 2023-06-27      16.0
1   apples 2023-07-25      36.0
2  bananas 2023-10-25      16.0
3  bananas 2023-12-27       0.0
4  oranges 2023-04-14       0.0
5  oranges 2023-07-13       0.0
6  oranges 2023-09-17      18.0
7  oranges 2023-10-05       0.0
8    pears 2023-07-08       0.0
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @jezrael, made an edit to your code. you can preselect columns within the `conditional_join` function

Comment: @sammywemmy - First time and it is super, thank you for it.

Answer (score 0):

The good people over at r/learnpython suggested this:

```
delta = pd.to_timedelta(7, unit='d')
ref["Total Quantity"] = ref.apply(
    lambda row: sales.loc[
        (sales["Fruit"] == row["Fruit"]) &
        (sales["Date"] >= row["Date"]-delta) &
        (sales["Date"] <= row["Date"]+delta),
        "Quantity"
    ].sum(),
    axis=1
)
```

which also works great

Comment: works, but is a row by row comparison, which wont offer you that vectorized optimisation.